# All possible combinations of two excel tables

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for all possible combinations out of two tables / lists in excel. Is there a possibility with VBA for a script code etc.? I'm out of creativity...

Table A x Table B = Table C (With all possible combinations from A and B)

Comment: Do 2 nested loops should do the trick

Comment: It depends on your data size and what kind of combinations you need. Check combinatory and permutations, because the output sometimes can be a few results or thousands of results. Show some effort, post what you've tried and also an expected output

Answer (score 0):

I have added some values in cells A1, A2, A3 and B1, B2, B3 and B4, and this simple macro sums all possible combinations of them:

```
Sub test()

i = 0
For Each celA In Range("A1:A3"):   ' loop through each cell in column A
  For Each celB In Range("B1:B4"): ' loop through each cell in column B
    Range("C1").Offset(i, 0).Value = celA.Value + celB.Value
    i = i + 1
  Next celB
Next celA
  
End Sub
```

The one for-loop inside the other is known as nested for-loops, exactly what you need for this kind of situations.